# Getting Whoops, there is no test to run while testing Salesforce Application

Tags: salesforce, cypress

I am testing sales force application using cypress, I have multiple it block inside describe block,
When I am running my test using test runner, I am getting whoops, there is no test to run, but tests are there to run under it block.
Not getting why I am getting this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPagC.png)

Comment: 1. Was your tests ever appear before in the Test Runner ?, 2.Were you able to trigger the tests via Node command prompt, ever before ?

Comment: Yes tests were appearing before, and one test under it block got executed, when it comes to second it block, there is no test to run message came.